# How do i change a column's reference table in laravel 7

Tags: database, laravel, migration

I made a mistake when i was building database, so as you will see in codes, my "order_id" column in "baskets" table is referenced from "customers" table but it should have been from "orders" table,

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('baskets', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('firm_id');
            $table->foreign('firm_id')
                    ->references('id')->on('firms')
                    ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('customer_id');
            $table->foreign('customer_id')
                    ->references('id')->on('customers')
                    ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('order_id');
            $table->foreign('order_id')
                    ->references('id')->on('customers')
                    ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('service_id');
            $table->foreign('service_id')
                    ->references('id')->on('services')
                    ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->decimal('price', 11, 2);
            $table->integer('quantity')->default(1);
            $table->string('note')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

So how can i change its reference table from "customers" to "orders" table.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: If you you have orders table `$table->foreign('order_id')
                    ->references('id')->on('orders')`

Comment: @sta i have "orders" table but i want to learn how do i change and run it. I've already started project and i can't refresh my database.

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking at the `dropForeign` method [(scroll down a little)](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints).

This method accepts an `$index` argument. The documentation already shows how to write this `$index`. Looking at the source code you can also see how this index is being generated. At some point the [`createIndexName`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php#L1427) method is being called during the [`foreign`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php#L544) call.

Looking at your code and the `createIndexName` method, we could guess the index name that is being created:

```
baskets_order_id_foreign
```

To round it up you might be able remove the foreign key by executing the following:

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('baskets', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('baskets_order_id_foreign');
        // Add your new foreign key
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I couldn't get it all sorry. The problem is my 'order_id' column is referenced form "customers" table instead of "orders" table. 
Are you sure generated code is "customers_service_id_foreign". I think it should be diffrent. How can i check it?
After finding the right generated code, how can i run it? "php artisan migrate" command will run it?

Comment: Can it be "baskets_order_id_foreign" instead of "baskets_service_id_foreign"? 
And then which command i will use to run it?

Comment: @MustafaArslan Please excuse me, it was indeed the incorrect column name. I have corrected my answer. I would suggest making a new migration for this.